# What Should I MarshalAs for Character Type in Fortran?

Tags: c#, interop, fortran

I am calling a fortran subroutine from C#. One of the parameter I have to pass in is character .i.e, in fortran that parameter is declared as

```
character, intent(in)  ::  bmat*1
```

The issue now is, in C# code, what should I marshaled it as? I know that for `integer`, I should marshal it as `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]`, but what about `character`?

**Edit:** This is my fortran code:

```
  subroutine chartest(bmat)
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::chartest
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:'chartest'::chartest
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES VALUE ::bmat
    character, intent(in)  ::  bmat*1
    if(bmat .eq. 'G')then
        print *, bmat
    else
        print *, ' no result '
    endif
   end
```

And this is my interop code:

```
    [DllImport(@"eigensolver_win32.dll")]
    public static extern void chartest( [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] char bmat);
```

This is how I call the routine:

```
    char bmat = 'G';
    EigenSolver32.chartest(bmat);
```

The result I got was "no result", indicating that the `if` is not fulfilled.

Comment: So what ended up working for you?

Comment: Did you need to use `ref byte` ?

Comment: @John, `ref byte` *is* needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `character` type in FORTRAN is an unsigned 8 bit quantity.

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
```

Will work.

The non-standard FORTRAN `byte` type is signed. it would be `UnmanagedType.I1`

Edit: C# char type is a Unicode (16 bit) type. The C# `byte` type is the one that matches the FORTRAN character type.

```
[DllImport(@"eigensolver_win32.dll")]
public static extern void chartest( [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] byte bmat);
```

Also, if I remember correctly all FORTRAN function arguments are passed by reference, so you may need this instead.

```
[DllImport(@"eigensolver_win32.dll")]
public static extern void chartest( [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] ref byte bmat);
```

And I think that `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]` is redundant for byte.

Comment: Thanks, I did as you told. But when I check the `bmat` inside my fortran program using the `if` statment (`if(bmat .eq. 'G')`), it returned a false. Anything I did wrong?

Comment: And, if I do  `print *, bmat`, I'll get back `G`. That's really weird.