# Type marshalling to call a fortran subroutine from C#

Tags: c#, fortran, marshalling

I'm trying to call a FORTRAN77 subroutine from C# code using P/invoke - in case you're interested, I'm trying to wrap some of the functionality offered by the ARPACK library ([http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/)). I have 2 questions.

---

First off, I couldn't find clear instructions anywhere regarding type marshalling in this context. More specifically, here are the types that are declared in my FORTRAN subroutine:

```
       subroutine getEigenVectors
      &   ( Matrix, n, which, nev, ncv, maxn, maxnev, maxncv, ldv, v, d)

 c     %------------------%
 c     | Scalar Arguments |
 c     %------------------%

       character        which*2
       integer          n, nev, maxn, maxnev, maxncv, ldv

 c     %-----------------%
 c     | Array Arguments |
 c     %-----------------%
 c
       Real           
      &                 Matrix(n,n), v(ldv,maxncv), d(maxncv,2)
```

I found some valuable info here: 
[What Should I MarshalAs for Character Type in Fortran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376585/what-should-i-marshalas-for-character-type-in-fortran), from which I implied (I might be wrong) that I should use:

- `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int` to pass in integers
- `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[]` to pass in character strings

However, I have absolutely no idea what to do with the `Real` arrays. **Does anyone have any idea on that?**

---

Secondly, I am confused as to whether I should pass my arguments as reference or not. I am by no means familiar with FORTRAN - I know, that makes the task a little difficult; however, only ARPACK does what I would like to do.I did read somewhere though that FORTRAN subroutines take all their arguments as reference by default. **Should I therefore pass all arguments as references?**

Thanks in advance for your help!
Guillaume

---

**EDIT** (8/6/11)

So here's my final take:

```
    [DllImport("Arpack.dll", EntryPoint = "#140")]
    private static extern void getEigenVectors(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] ref float[,] matrix, 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] ref int n,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] ref byte[] which,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int whichLength,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] ref int nev, 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] ref int ncv,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] ref int maxn,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] ref int maxnev,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] ref int maxncv,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] ref int ldv,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] ref float[,] v,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] ref float[,] d
    );
```

Several things I did here:

- Pass `int` objects marshalled as `UnmanagedType.I4` to match FORTRAN `integer` objects
- Pass `float[,]` objects of size (m, n) and marshalled as `UnmanagedType.LPArray` to match FORTRAN `Real(n,m)` objects
- Pass `byte[]` objects obtained marshalled as `UnmanagedType.LPArray` to match FORTRAN `Character*n` objects. The `byte[]` objects are computed as follows:

  ```
  System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
  byte[] which = encoding.GetBytes(myString);
  ```
- Pass an `int` object BY VALUE and marshalled as `UnmanagedType.I4` to indicate the length of the string. Note that I tried to put that argument right after the string as well as at the end of the arguments list.

This is my best shot - neither this nor all the other things I tried worked. The method will execute, however it exits super fast (when it's supposed to be doing some pretty severe computations). Moreover, my 3 arrays are transformed into weird uni-dimensional arrays. Here what the debugger gives me:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: ARPACK is truly wonderful. What I do with fortran 77 code is run it through f2c -a to make it into C code and then build that. If you are familiar with C then you may find that simpler.

Comment: Be aware that Fortran passes a length variable around with each character string. It may be passed immediately after the character string or at the end depending on your compiler and compiler options.

Comment: your marshalas attributes are not needed I think for example int defaults to I4. Your matrices will surely not be marshalled right like that. You need to run the arpack code inside a debugger and see  how the parameters arrive. Why use utf8?ht like that. You need to run the arpack code inside a debugger and see  how the parameters arrive. Why use utf8?

Comment: Hum, you're right, not sure why I used utf-8. How is the CHARACTER type encoded then? I searched for it and couldn't find anything. On your 2nd element: definitely a better option than random stabs in the dark. I'm wondering how to do that though. Sorry, I'm a complete beginner with all this...!

Comment: In my experience doing such a thing, the more your over-specify the parameters with `MarshalAs()` the more failure I see. Add only the attributes that are absolutely necessary. For example a `float` is automatically marshaled as `REAL`. See also if your compiler has a `!DEC$ ATTRIBUTE VALUE` specification to reduce the number of `ref` arguments in *C#*

Comment: And see related post .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231751/calling-fortran-dll-from-c-and-assigning-values-to-array-of-structures

Comment: You cannot pass multidimensional arrays as `float[,]`. Also arrays are already references and do not need the `ref`. A fortran `REAL :: A(2,2)` is passed as `float A[]` with 4 elements. In order they are `A11` `A21` `A12` `A22` as FORTRAN differs from C in the ordering of the elements.

Comment: If you know C at all then it will be a lot easier to use `f2c -a` to turn the Fortran into C code. If you don't know C then please ignore this suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you start with some small test code. Compile a FORTRAN .dll with some subroutines with simple parameters and play around with *C#* to get the calling to work. Also you may wish to wrap the Fortran with many arguments into a single structure (`TYPE` keyword), which makes the interop so much easier.

Here is a working example that you can use the get many ideas of how it works.

Original FORTRAN code:

```
  SUBROUTINE CALC2(BLKL,BLKW, N_LAMINA,N_SLICE, LOAD, SLOP,SKW,    &
                    DIA1,DIA2, Y1, Y2, N1, N2, DROP1, DROP2,        &
                    PARRAY, P_MAX, P_MAX_INDEX, ENDEFCT)
  !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: CALC2
  !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:'CALC2' :: CALC2
  !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES VALUE :: BLKL, BLKW, N_LAMINA, N_SLICE, LOAD, SLOP, SKW
  !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES VALUE :: DIA1, DIA2, Y1, Y2, N1, N2
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER*4, INTENT(IN) ::N_LAMINA, N_SLICE
  REAL*4, INTENT(IN) :: BLKL, BLKW, LOAD, SLOP, SKW,     &
                        DIA1, DIA2, Y1, Y2, N1, N2,   &
                        DROP1(MAX_LAMINA), DROP2(MAX_LAMINA)
  REAL*4, INTENT(OUT):: PARRAY(MAX_PATCH), P_MAX
  INTEGER*4, INTENT(OUT) :: P_MAX_INDEX, ENDEFCT
  INTEGER*4 :: NDIAG, N_PATCH
  REAL*4 :: SLNG, SWID
  REAL*4 :: DROPS_1(MAX_LAMINA), DROPS_2(MAX_LAMINA)

...

  END SUBROUTINE CALC2
```

with various scalar and array values in real and integer form. For example `DROP1` is input 1D array. `PARRAY` is outputing a 2D array as a 1D array. `BLKL` are input floats.

Notice the `!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES VALUE` decoration to avoid declaring everything as `ref`.

In *C#* the code is called by

```
    [DllImport("mathlib.dll")]
    static extern void CALC2(float major_dim, float minor_dim, 
        int N_lamina, int N_slices, float total_load, 
        float slope, float skew, float diameter_1, float diameter_2, 
        float youngs_1, float youngs_2, float nu_1, float nu_2, 
        float[] drops_1, float[] drops_2, float[] pressures, 
        ref float p_max, ref int p_max_index, ref EndEffect end_effect);

...
   {
        float max_pressure = 0;
        int max_pressure_index = 0;
        float[] pressures = new float[Definition.MAX_PATCH];
        EndEffect end_effect = EndEffect.NO;

        CALC2(length, width, lamina_count, slice_count, load, slope, skew, 
            dia_1, dia_2, y_1, y_2, n_1, n_2, drops_1, drops_2, pressures, 
            ref max_pressure, ref max_pressure_index, ref end_effect);
    }
```

*note* I do not pass any strings.

Comment: ja72, thanks for all your comments and suggestions. Your tips here and there helped me the most make this work, so I will grant you my points. It all worked in the end thanks to your advice, all I had to abandon was string parameters - not absolutely necessary for me.

Comment: Note that `!DEC$` declarations are not portable (though since windows is involved it is likely IFV is being used, which does know these).  You can re-implmenet the Fortran in a portable way using `iso_c_binding` features of modern Fortran which is widely implemented in any semi-recent compiler.

Comment: I know, but this is an old posting.

Answer (score 1):

1) Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point):

> Single precision, called "float" in the C language family, **and
>   "real" or "real*4" in Fortran**. This is a binary format that occupies
>   32 bits (4 bytes) and its significand has a precision of 24 bits
>   (about 7 decimal digits).

So marshal it as a float. You could have tested that one, it's either a float or a double.

2) Quoting this [Fortran 77 Tutorial](http://www.physics.nau.edu/~bowman/PHY520/F77tutor/11_subprograms.html):

> Fortran 77 uses the so-called call-by-reference paradigm. This means
>   that instead of just passing the values of the function/subroutine
>   arguments (call-by-value), the memory address of the arguments
>   (pointers) are passed instead.

Pass every parameter by reference.

Comment: fortran matrices are col major too don't forget!

Comment: _"So marshal it as a float. You could have tested that one, it's either a float or a double."_

Channeling Raymond Chen, now, are we?

Comment: Wrapping up what you guys said then, it seems I should pass `float[,]` or `double[,]` elements without forgetting to transpose the original arrays. I'll try that and let you know how things go.

Comment: Do *not* pass arrays by reference as they are already references. `ref float[] A` is incorrect.