# Making Fortran dll and calling it from C#

Tags: c#, dll, fortran

I have a function in a Fortran executable and I need to make it a dll file so I can call it's functions from a C# program

```
      FUNCTION TSAT11(P) 
C     ** IGNORE IMPLEMENTATION **
      TSAT11 = SX*TSAT2(X) + SXL1*TSAT3-273.15 
      RETURN 
      END
```

P is a float and the function returns a float

The thing here that I don't know anything in fortran nor calling dlls from C#, so please explain a little more.

I'm using Compaq Visual Fortran and C# 2008.

Thank you for your time.

(If you like you can see the full code [Here](http://www.mediafire.com/?r49g04w5qncqgr4) [It's a program to calculate water and steam properties])

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/123841   ?

Comment: Please include how is defined `P`, and what the function returns as far as types and array dimensions.

Comment: Do know how to make DLLs with your Fortran compiler?

Comment: The whole `** IGNORE IMPLEMENTATION **` comment does not acknowledge the multiple possible calling-convention differences between Fortran/C-languages. If `P` were a character you'd have to acknowledge the hidden length parameter, etc.

Comment: I void using return values, and instead I used `out` parameters.

Comment: Look at this answer on how to get started with `C#` and `Fortran` interop. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6969640/380384

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an example using single precision floats.

Fortran library contains:

```
FUNCTION TSAT11(P) 
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:'TSAT11' :: TSAT11
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: TSAT11
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES VALUE :: P
REAL, INTENT(IN) :: P   
REAL :: TSAT11
    ! Examle calculation
    TSAT11 = P - 273.15
RETURN 
END FUNCTION
```

With the calling function

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("calc.dll")]
    static extern float TSAT11(float P);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float p = 300f;
        float t = TSAT11(p);
        // returns 26.8500061
    } 
 }
```

Similarly for an array (must declare the size)

```
FUNCTION TSAT12(P,N) 
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:'TSAT12' :: TSAT12
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: TSAT12
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES VALUE :: N
INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: N
REAL, INTENT(IN) :: P(N)
REAL :: TSAT12
    ! Examle calculation
    TSAT12 = SQRT( DOT_PRODUCT(P,P) )
RETURN 
END FUNCTION
```

with calling `C#` code

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("calc.dll")]
    static extern float TSAT12(float[] P, int N);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float[] p2=new float[] { 0.5f, 1.5f, 3.5f };
        float t2=TSAT12(p2, p2.Length);
        //returns 3.84057283
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks man you saved my life, I have a deadline tomorrow and your answer was everything I looked for.
One thing missing `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

Comment: @workoverflow - I have to say that sometimes the C# function needs a `ref` to the first element to the array instead of the full array. Like `TSAT12(ref p2[0])` and declaration `static extern float TSAT12(ref float P, int N);`

Answer (score 1):

You could use P/Invoke. Here's [an article](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/calling-fortran-function-or-subroutine-in-dll-from-c-code/) which provides an example. As far as compiling your Fortran code into an unmanaged DLL you could [create a DLL Project](http://protodesign-inc.com/doc/SansGUI/creating_dll_projects.htm) in CVF.

Comment: Consider adding a `!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES VALUE :: P` decoration that avoids having to use `ref` arguments and passes by value. So instead of `foo(ref p)` you call with `foo(p)`.