# Run Fortran DLL with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, fortran, dllimport, intel-fortran

I develop a website with Visual Studio 2010. I want to run a Fortran DLL. I used Intel Visual Fortran to create a .dll and to test how to use it. My code is:

```
      SUBROUTINE SIMPSON (N,H,I)

     !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, DECORATE, ALIAS : "SIMPSON" :: SIMPSON
     !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE::N
     !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE::H
     !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE::I
      INTEGER N,H,I

      I=N+H

      RETURN
      END
```

which practically takes two integers, adds them and return the result. Now I have the .dll I don't know how to run it with Visual Studio. Can anyone who knows please give me steps to follow?

Answer (score 2):

I do this all the time. What I do, is in the calling project (`C#`, `VB.NET`) I add the `.dll` output to the project as an existing item, with `Add as Link` option. Then I set it to copy if newer in the project tree.

[image: Add Item]

[image: Add As Link]

[image: Copy If Newer]

In the end it follows the binary when you compile it into the `bin/Debug` or `bin/Release` folders.

With `C#` you then use the `[DllImport()]` attrbiute like this:

```
[DllImport("trex_pc.dll")]
static extern Simpson(ref int N, ref int H, ref int I);
```

For more details look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10318273/380384) answer from me.

Comment: When i use it for a web application it works fine,but when i use it for a website it says that dll was not found.any idea why?

Comment: Does the `.dll` copy when you publish the website? I really do not know at all how web development handles binaries.

Comment: No,it did not.I added a link with the folder that contains the .dll.Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a Console project in IVF and link in your DLL. That may require producing a .lib file containing references to your DLL. I'm not 100% sure how to do that, although perhaps it was automatically created for you.

After the library is linked in, you can simply `call simpson` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Post-Build Event in the dll Property Pages:

- Click right on DLL-project in Solution Explorer
- goto Build Events - post-Build Events
- Command Line  `copy/y "$(OutDir)\$(ProjectName).dll" "$(SolutionDir)\bin\debug\"`
  The DLL will be copied each time you build the DLL or Solution.
  The target location might be different.