# Can't Find DLL (Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: c#, dll

Right now I'm trying to write a program for a sensor to collect data with.  The sensor manufacturer released an SDK that has example code in it.  I haven't made any changes to the code and am only attempting to use their examples to figure out how to make my own code work with the sensor.  I've opened it up with Visual Studio 2008 and attempted to run the code as both debug and release.  In both cases, it stops when it can't find the manufacturer's dll files.

I've copied the files in question to the same folder with the project in it and the problem persists.  I've been to multiple forums and downloaded things and nothing has worked.  I've run Dependency Walker which indicated issues with ieframe.dll and ieshims.dll.  I copied both files from the IE folder and into the system32 folder and then registered them with an elevated command prompt.  This fixed the issue with ieshims but ieframe persists.  I tried downloading the latest IE (11) but that just introduced more issues and failed to fix the ieframe issue.

I'm not really sure how to proceed and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide more information, are these managed DLLs (i.e. .NET DLLs) or native DLLs? What does your code look like for using the DLLs?

Comment: Wrong folder, they need to go into your bin\Debug folder.

Comment: The DLLs are unmanaged as far as I know.  Their code is supposed to provide access to the sensor even in managed code (which I'm more familiar with).  Their code imports various functions from the DLL using [DllImport("their.dll")] followed by the function and the inputs, like private static extern Int32 Function(int number);.  It does this repeatedly before the main body.  The issue arises in the code when they first try to call one of those functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dll needs to be in the same folder as the executable. I use a shortcut/link within VS to achieve this. The result looks like this:

[image: pic]

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10392202/380384) for more details and an example.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting other errors besides the .DLL errors? If so, you need to get ride of those errors. Once you get rid of those errors your DLL errors should go away then.

Comment: It was just the DLL errors.  The other errors I was talking about were from Dependency Walker.